# Can I fade the edges of a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure a way of having the bottom of a webpage have a z-index: 1; of this PNG image: http://i.imgur.com/PiRUJ8h.png so that when people scroll, it's as if the text on a page is fading in. I hope that makes sense. I want to make the width of the image 100% to the webpage dimension for everyone's screen resolution of course, which can't be done with div style in HTML, which is annoying. I wish I could do width=100% or something with div style but it can't be done, so is there a way to pull this off?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is closer to what you're looking for:

```css
.container {position:relative }
.content {
  overflow:scroll; 
  height: 200px; /* <-- could be anything. just for demo */
}

.gradient {
  position:absolute; bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
  height: 40px;
  /* use a png if you prefer, but this works: */
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1)); 
  pointer-events:none; /* don't block clicks */
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

(The effect is a bit subtle; change the colors of the gradient to more clearly see what it's doing)

Based on comments below, here is the same technique applied to a box shadow (but stacked above the content rather than underneath as in the other answer):

```css
.container {position:relative }
.content {
  overflow:scroll; 
  height: 200px; /* <-- could be anything. just for demo */
}

.gradient {
  position:absolute; bottom:0;left:0;right:0;top:0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px #000 inset;
  pointer-events:none; /* don't block clicks */
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly no :( I'm aiming for what Praveen Kumar did but as an overlay instead, where there's a shadow around the edge of the webpage that is over everything else. That's why I mentioned the "z-index: 1;" thing, since I've always done that in HTML to overlap, but not sure what I'm doing here.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, the technique is applicable to any style you like.

Comment: Still no dice. I'm actually not seeing a gradient at all with your code.

Comment: I think you checked before I updated...?  Are you still not seeing it?

Comment: It's all a little confusing for me since I'm not really intermediate with CSS, but I'm getting the gyst of it. I've already got a lot of other code on my webpage, you see. I'm not sure if there's anything interfering or not, but I have put all of your code in and it's showing nothing changed. Yeah I've checked after you updated. Thanks for sticking around by the way.

Comment: Are you seeing the effect in the snippet? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually, you know what, I don't see anything in the snippet except a scroll box with text.

Comment: There's really not much going on in this code, maybe it'd be easier to just explain it:  All I've done is absolute-position a `<div>` above the rest of the content, put whatever you want in it -- gradients, box shadows, whatever -- and used pointer-events:none to allow clicks to pass through to the original layer.   (Absolute-positioned content gets stacked on top of other content implicitly, but if you have other absolute-positioned content you'll need to set a higher z-index on the overlay.)

Comment: (The overlay could either be over the full page -- in which case you'd put it at the root level of the DOM -- or over a specific node, as in the `.container` in my example.)

Comment: "I don't see anything in the snippet except a scroll box with text" -- the first snippet has a fade-to-white gradient at the bottom, because that's what I thought you meant by "as if the text on a page is fading in"...  as I said it's subtle, you can change the colors to see it more clearly.  The second snippet has a big ol' black box shadow similar to Praveen's, but stacked above rather than below the content.

Comment: Haha I know that, I changed the RGBA to black :) Still didn't see anything. Anyway, in the other answer's comments I gave an image I made quickly so you both can get an easier understanding.

Comment: I didn't include all the vendor-specific markup variations for the gradient, so it may not appear in all browsers; you can look those up if you need them.   The box shadow (second snippet) does exactly what you had in your image, as far as I can tell; if that's still not what you're looking for can you please clarify what the difference is?

Comment: The webpage I'm editing on doesn't work with that as far as I'm aware since my webpage is a sub page of a website that isn't owned by me, it's my profile essentially. As far as I know, html, text/css and javascript are the only things that work. Besides, I know nothing about vendors, sorry about taking up so much of your time, I think I'll leave this be, thanks for trying though Daniel.

Comment: Still just css: "vendors" as in different browsers requiring different prefixed css instructions -- `-webkit-gradient`, `-moz-gradient`, etc.   I generally use a preprocessor to take care of those so tend to forget that they are necessary when hand-writing code.   Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `<div>` or `<body>` or any block level element in that case, and yeah, can be done using CSS in Modern Browsers. Check out the snippet:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  height: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

If you want the shadow to be staying at one place, you might use `position: absolute` for the content.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.wrapper {position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; overflow: auto; padding: 15px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

> **Note:** As said in the comments, the W3C recommends not styling the `html` element. I have done in the second snippet just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Note: the W3C recommends not styling the html element.

Comment: Vendor prefixes haven't been needed for `box-shadow` for [quite some time](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow).

Comment: @Rob do you have any reference for that claim? CSS is applicable to all HTML elements. Not all properties actually affect certain elements, but I've never read that you shouldn't apply style to `<html>`...

Comment: @AndréDion http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background I only read this a few days ago but it was for background properties in this context so I somewhat mis-remembered it. However, this is something that should be looked into to see how far, and where, that same statement applies.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I follow? but this is what I got out of it. Hope this helps!!!!

```css
p{
  color: white;
  margin:20px;

}

h1{
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px red;
  position: fixed; 
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-left: 32%;
  }

.image{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('http://webcdn.triongames.com/defiance/images/splash/defiance_newshrub_3kpx_w_2.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-top: 10%;
 }

.container{
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black; 
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.gradient {
  position:fixed;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0),RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1)); 
  pointer-events:none;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0
 }
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>


<div class='image'></div>
<div class='container'>
  <p>Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet abyssin jettster jabba katarn arkanian ti klatooinian vos nelvaanian darth. Nadon droch axmis droopy maximilian jar ki-adi-mundi. Wharl priapulin oppo rattatak bibble jettster skakoan. Droid lobot freedon fett dulok tib rishi. Taun xexto carnor katarn shaak kashyyyk kushiban shmi. Woostoid dantooine kasan timoliini joruus jade soontir raynar vima-da-boda. Fisto d8 kit darth epicanthix kubaz jerec vor. Bria cordé onimi karrde rahm tatooine tatooine aurra. Kyp rebo chadra-fan habassa emtrey falleen mccool.

Sola clawdite dunhausen antilles coway gand ubb. Neimoidian darth porkins gotal skirata gado vel. Klatooinian joelle boss duro. Darth cal balosar veila tiin teek san malastare gonk. Billaba kendal dak thisspias braxant. Caamasi zorba darth lando seerdon er'kit selonian shadda. Veila sabé bibble nute leia. Di iktotchi nass nosaurian wicket nunb mccool. C-3p0 ord lars winter geonosis whill nute jinn. Mustafarian aparo tib luuke aayla jeremoch sith han piell. Skywalker bail teneniel kohl. Quence argazdan solo fisto.   </p>
  <div class='gradient'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really nice! But not what I wanted at all, haha. It's fine, I decided to drop this topic since it seems like what I want can't be done. I could easily do it by finding the dimensions of my page and then doing an overlay with a PNG image of a shadow with div style position absolute, but that would only work for my screen resolution, not other resolutions. It's fine though, thanks for trying to help!